# Retrofit2 send 10 equals request with diferent parameter and return one response

Tags: android, observable, retrofit2, rx-android

I have method:

```
Observable<ProductsResponse> products =  restApiFactory.getProductService().getProducts(CategoryID)
```

how can I make 10 request with different ID and return ONE reault:

```
for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
Observable<ProductsResponse> products =  restApiFactory.getProductService().getProducts(i)
}
```

How can I get merge result?

```
public class ProductsResponse {
  private String status;
  private String message;
  private List<ProductItem> productItems;
}
```

I need List with data from each request

Comment: Which one do you want to get: the first or the last?

Comment: Didn't get it. You want to merge the results of the 10 requests or only keep one? If it's the second option, why do you do the other 9 requests?

Comment: first to last. @Eselfar each request has different parameter and return data. I need data fron all requests

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do something like:

```
List<Observable< ProductsResponse>> productsResponseObservableList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
    productsResponseObservableList.add(restApiFactory.getProductService().getProducts(i));
}

Observable.combineLatest(productsResponseObservableList, args -> Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOf(args, args.length, ProductsResponse[].class)))
    .subscribe(responseList -> {
    });
```

Comment: @ip696 did you try this?